# font-awesome fa-trash not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome in a rails app and the fa-trash works on my development machine but when I deploy the fa-trash stops working and I get a different icon. The other icons however do work fine in production, it's just fa-trash.

If I use fa-trash-o that works fine. Here is an example of my three icons, show, edit & delete, where delete is supposed to be a trash can.

[image: example]

Here is the code which does the icons

```
    <td class="th_icon icon_table">
      <a id="show" href="/api#/costings/{{costing.id}}"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
      <a id="edit" href="/api#/costings/{{costing.id}}/edit"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a id="delete" href="" ng-hide="costing.code == 1" ng-confirm-click="destroy(costing.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
```

I've cleared out my assets and re-compiled them & restarted the server and cleared out my cache in the browser, test

**UPDATE**

My install

I'm using the rails-assets in my Gemfile to get the 4.2 version of Font Awesome

```
gem 'rails-assets-font-awesome'
```

In my sass file

```
*= require font-awesome
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this doesn't work. I'm using font-awesome-rails 4.2 and can't get any of the new icons to show up. All the old ones still works though.

Comment: I can get the new icons to work in development using the gem 'rails-assets-font-awesome' but not when I deploy to my staging server. So it does sound like a rails assets / caching problem I've got.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like fa-trash is new in font-awesome 4.2. Though I'm not entirely sure if this is the case, but it really looks as if in production, an older version of font-awesome is being loaded (for whatever reason).

How are you getting the icons? Are they local, or [the getting started link](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) on the font-awesome site?

Comment: I've just added how I've install font-awesome above.

Comment: I would require trying a different 4.2 only icon (instead of fa-trash) to see if there is a similar problem. If so, at least we have a clue of what the issue is. 

My knowledge about the asset pipeline isn't very strong, but I imagine it has something to do with that.

Comment: It seems to be only the new icons in 4.2, just tried fa-yelp and few other new ones and get the same result as fa-trash

Answer (score 0):

The last icon that I can load is "bomb" - every icon after that, well 'bombs' - comes up blank on the screen and doesn't make a pseudo-element in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use font-awesome-rails gem?

I have had the same problem on one of our setups. The problem was that I had a folder with old FontAwesome (otf, wolff etc.) files included in asset. I removed the files then the gem will look for the correct files.

Comment: Swapping to font-awesome-rails gem stops most but not all of my font-awesome icons. This creates a larger problem than using rails-assets-font-awesome

Answer (score 0):

A little late here but make sure you are using an 'i' tag surrounding the icon.

Good:

```
<i class="fas fa-trash text-danger ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Bad:

```
<div class="fas fa-trash text-danger ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```